# How to write order bydescending time in linq in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

**How to get the model order by descending time?**

I mean I need the latest record in the model first. but here I'm getting the oldest record in my model first. while I'm trying to make model order by ascending. I'm getting the error:

> doesn't exist definition of `orderbydescending`

```
Public ActionResult Marker()
        {
            var model = new AssetTrackersViewModel();
            model.AssetTrackers.Add(getAssetDetails("E"));
            model = model.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.time)).ToList();//getting error does not contain defination for order by descending. 
        }

private AssetTracker getAssetDetails(string deviceID, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
        {
            var assetTracker = new AssetTracker { deviceid = deviceID };
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"url");
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "a2Vy==";
            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
            using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);
                var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA=") && (fromDate == null || fromDate.Value.Date <= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && (toDate == null || toDate.Value.Date >= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date))
                 .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame.Substring(a.dataFrame.Length - 12))
                 .Select(g => g.First()).OrderBy(a => a.timestamp);

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
                    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data);//converting base 64 to hexcode
                 ......
                    string updtime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(item.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
                 
                }
                return assetTracker;
            }
        }

public class AssetTrackerViewModel
  {
            
    public string time { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: `.OrderByDesc(a => a.timestamp);`

Comment: thanks its working now. but why can't i write in   model = model.OrderByDescending(..)

Comment: Because `OrderBy` is a member of the `Enumerable` class. So if your model isn't, there is nothing which makes `OrderBy` magically appears. If you have a list, collection or something like that; i.e. more than 1 of your model, then you can order the data. `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx